# How to set up different "main source files" in Visual Studio with most files shared?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My C++ project in Visual Studio contains a couple different "main" files, e.g. `main-visualize.cpp`, `main-calculate.cpp`, `main-test.cpp`. These files all define their own `main()` functions but include mostly the same files.

What is a good way to set this environment up using Visual Studio?

It seems like they should be three different projects in the same solution, but the projects should share *all* files except those main files.

Comment: yes, you can make 3 project to include different main.cpp

Comment: Put the shared files into a static library project. Then create the three `main` projects, each depending on that static library.

Comment: For `main-test` you could check out Visual Studio's Unit Test support. That's even part of the free Express Editions.